# Prune empty commits in ref range using git-filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

Suppose I have a tree such as

```
0 - A - 1 - E1 - 2 - B - E2 - 3 - ..
                      \
                       c - 4 - ..
```

I want to prune empty commits in a range `A..B` and end up with:

```
0 - A - 1 - 2` - B` - E2` - 3` - ..
                  \
                   c` - 4` - ..
```

Running

```
git filter-repo --prune-empty always --refs A..B
```

Results in no change, presumably since B.. is not rewritten.

Running

```
git filter-repo --prune-empty always --refs A..B --replaces-refs update-or-add && \
git filter-repo --prune-empty auto
```

seems to yield the desired result. Thing is, I know very little about replace-refs. I wonder if this is the right way to go about this problem.

I should add that I'm not rewriting public history. For all intents and purposes, the history is just within the local repository.

Comment: Based on the documentation (I have not looked at the source), `--replace-refs` is strictly a control knob for `refs/replace/*` names as created by `git replace` or by an earlier `git filter-repo` that was told to create such names. Using `--refs` already enables `--partial` but it's not at all clear to me that it only prunes "empty" commits in any specified A..B range. The documentation doesn't say what happens with negative refs (`A..B` means `B ^A`; `^A` is a negative ref to `A`).